# Passing a method as a parameter .net

Tags: vb.net

I have been searching for quite a while today for an answer to my question but without success. I don't even know if its possible but I'll try my luck here.

Lets say i have this function somewhere in a class:

```
Public Sub sub1(i as Integer, uc as UserControl)
    ...
End Sub
```

And somewhwere else, in an other method i have this call:

```
sub1(46, new UserControl())
```

The problem is that i want to pass a UserControl with, lets say, a background colored in blue but it must be defined inside the method call. In other words, i want to pass an object with some properties that are modifed outside the constructor and everything must be done inside the method call. I'm thinking of something like that:

```
sub1(9387, {Dim uc as new UserControl()
            uc.BackColor = Color.Blue
            return uc} )
```

I understand that i could define a UserControl and modify it before the method call but my real situation is way more complex than that. Anyway I just want to know if it is currently possible and if yes show me some examples. In my research i found that i could do some delegate or use some "lambda" expression but I didn't find a solution that perfectly solve my question. And again, I must not write a single character of code outside the method call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you expand the UserControl Class to have a custom constructor that takes the background color as a parameter?

Comment: Like i said, "And again, I must not write a single character of code outside the method call.". I know that its not the best solution, i just want to know if its possible.

Comment: If you absolutely need to, see @DonA's answer. You should, however, **avoid** such complicated constructs, because your debugging experience would suffer. It does not matter how many lines of code your method has, it matters how fast you can understand it, find and fix the problem. For this case, what if you then decide to have 20 properties populated? What if 10 of those would outsource work to an external service, separate thread etc.? You either get a really big `With` or just back to using plain old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Immediately-invoked functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) are possible in VB.NET:

```
Dim result As Integer = (Function() As Integer
                             Return 1
                         End Function)()
```

Or in your example:

```
sub1(9387, (Function()
                Dim uc As New UserControl()
                uc.BackColor = Color.Blue
                Return uc
            End Function)())
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. The only thing is that it seems that we cannot return all type of object. I tested if i could, by example, return a System.Drawing.Pen and it said: "Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Pen' because 'Sytem.drawing.Pen' is not a delegate type.". I don't know if there is a solution to this. Other than that its good to know that we can do this kind of thing.

Comment: @user3267032 It shouldn't be trying to do any conversion. Make sure you include `()` to call the function so it will pass the return value instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
sub1(9387, New UserControl With {.BackColor = Color.Blue})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you can simply use property initializers:

```
sub1(9387, New UserControl With { .BackColor = Color.Blue })
```

Comment: Alright but if its not a property that i want to call on the object? Can i use this solution with subs and functions inside the object?

Comment: @user3267032: Like what exactly? Please elaborate **in your question**.

Comment: So you're talking about calling a method after you've constructed it, like New UserControl().DoSomething()?  That would require some sort of fluent-like interface.  I would look at what @Taegost suggested.